# vb.net web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

i have this simple web service

```
<WebMethod()> _
 Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return "[1255545454545,4]"
 End Function
```

and this will be at the client side 
>

```
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
          data: "{}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) {
              alert(response);
          },
          failure: function(msg) {
              alert(msg);
          }
      });
  });
```

how can i have the real value instead of the [object object] that i get

Comment: What do you expect the "real value" to be? You're returning JSON and it's getting parsed as an array with two elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to access response.d. It's a Asp.Net feature.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
          alert(response.d);
          alert(response.d[0]);
          alert(JSON.stringify(response));
      },
      failure: function(msg) {
          alert(msg);      
      }
  });
```

http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/

Comment: can you give us some explanation

Comment: The link http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/ explains everything. Your problem is solved?